# How to equals a single character in string and then calculate it

Tags: java, string, equals

"This is my code"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int letter_count = 0;
    String  check_word = new String ("How to equals a single character in string and then calculate it ");
    String single_letter = " ";
    int i = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < check_word.length(); i++ ) {

        single_letter = check_word.substring(0);

        if (single_letter.equals("a") ); {
            letter_count ++;

        }
    }
    System.out.println ( " - \"a\""  + " was found " + letter_count + " times");
}
```

Comment: In addition to the above comments, I'll point out an obvious one -- remove the semoclon after the `if`.

Comment: I know, but when I run the String ( How to equals an character in string and then calculate it? 

- "a" was found 60 times.

Comment: I can guess what you mean by "equals a character" -- I'm guessing you mean "see whether the character is equal to another character." I have no idea what "calculate it" means.

Comment: @yshavit They want to count the number of times a particular character occurs in the string. In this case, the character `a` in the string `How to equals a single character in string and then calculate it `.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confused about what the substring function does. This line:

```
single_letter = check_word.substring(0);
```

essentially returns the whole of `check_word` and stores it inside of `single_letter`. I suspect what you actually wanted was this:

```
single_letter = check_word.substring(i, i + 1);
```

to get the single letter at that position.

You could also change it to:

```
if(check_word.charAt(i) == 'a') {
    letter_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of your problems is that there is `;` after your `if (single_letter.equals("a") )` condition so your code

```
if (single_letter.equals("a") ); {
    letter_count ++;
}
```

effectively is the same as

```
if (single_letter.equals("a") ){
    //empty block "executed" conditionally 
}
//block executed regardless of result in `if` condition
{
    letter_count ++;
}
```

---

Other problem is that

```
single_letter = check_word.substring(0);
```

will get substring of `check_word` from index `0` which means that it will store same string  as `check_word`. Consider using `charAt` method with `i` instead of `0`. This will return simple `char` so you will need to compare it with `==` like `check_word.charAt(i)=='a'`.

Other (and probably better) approach would be just iterating over all characters of string with

```
for (char ch : check_word.toCharArray()){
    //test value of ch
}
```

Comment: also having this check_word.substring(0); should be  this check_word.substring(i).

Comment: @Manhoman No, `substring(i)` returns remainder of the string beginning at position `i`. you need `charAt(i)` or `substring(i,i+1)`

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int letter_count = 0;
    char[] check_word = "How to equals a single character in string and then calculate it "
            .toCharArray();
    char single_letter = 'a';

    for (int i = 0; i < check_word.length; i++) {
        if (single_letter == check_word[i]) {
            letter_count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" - \"a\"" + " was found " + letter_count + " times");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a character, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int letter_count = 0;
    String  check_word = new String ("How to equals a single character in string and then calculate it ");
    char toCheck = 'a';

    for (int i = 0; i < check_word.length(); i++) {
        char cursor = check_word.charAt(i);
        if (cursor == toCheck) {
            letter_count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println ( " - \"a\""  + " was found " + letter_count + " times");
}
```